# Mapstruct unable to create Beans when using AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am working on a project where my application uses several third party jars which are build on spring-core. These jars have duplicate class names hence, I am using AnnotationBeanNameGenerator to register these bean-names uniquely by giving them fully-qualified-path name. Now, my application also have mapstruct. I can see the mapstruct is not able create beans. Though, the mapstruct impl classes are properly generated in target folder.
NOTE: Earlier the mapstruct was working all fine. When I introduced AnnotationBeanNameGenerator, it started throwing error at runtime.
How shall I create mapper beans manually??
For unique Bean name generation I am using this code:

```
public class UniqueBeanNameGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        String val = definition.getBeanClassName();
        logger.info(val);
        return val;
    }
}
```

Mapstruct code:

```
    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    public interface PayloadConversion {
    
        
        TargetPayload mapFrom(SourcePayload req);
}
```

Class which uses the MapStruct:

```
 @Component
public class ConvertType {

@Inject
private PayloadConversion convert;
  
}
```

App start class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator=UniqueBeanNameGenerator.class)
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

Error stack during app start:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field mapper in com.dataconversion.ConvertType required a bean of type 'com.dataconversion.PayloadConversion' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.dataconversion.PayloadConversion' in your configuration.
```

Comment: And without the error you get you expect us to be able to answer this? The fact that you use this custom `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator` probably also means you have a `@ComponentScan` which might not cover everything needed leading to missing beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum Here is the error stack during app start. Yes, I am using component scan. I have edited the question with error stack.

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field mapper in com.dataconversion.ConvertType required a bean of type 'com.dataconversion.PayloadConversion' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.dataconversion.PayloadConversion' in your configuration.

Comment: Replace `@Inject` with `@Autowired`. If your `Application` class isn't in `com.dataconversion` things might break. You can try instead of using `@ComponentScan` to set it on the `SpringApplication` class. Something like `new SpringApplication(Application.class).setBeanNameGenerator(new UniqueBeanNameGenerator()).run(args);`

Comment: thanks it worked. Could you please explain the reason to use Autowired and remove the UniqueBeanNameGenerator from @ComponentScan ?

Comment: Not sure if it is/was the combination. But I believe (IIRC) that `@Inject` tries always to do a lookup by name+type, now as the names changed that doesn't resolve anymore. Whereas `@Autowired` does always by type and as a fallback type+name. The `@ComponentScan` can influence the packages that are being scanned, although I doubt it was in this case as it was on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the same location. So I suspect it was solely due to using `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`.